# Access non-Array Javascript property as integer index e.g. NamedNodeMap

Tags: javascript

So `NamedNodeMap` is a javascript class with methods `getNamedItem`, `setNamedItem`, and a few others.  It includes a read-only integer property `length` and is accessible by index, e.g. `attributes[0]`.

My question is how can this be implemented in Javascript?  it is not an `Array` and does not include `push` or `pop` methods.  But Javascript properties are strings, 0 is a number and to my knowledge it's not coerced to string when accessing with the `[ ]` notation.

How is this implemented in Javascript code, and how is it syntactically processed?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is coerced into a string...

```
x = {}

x[0] = 3;

x["0"] // 3;
```

... which makes this not very interesting to implement:

```
attributes = {}
attributes.length = attributes[0] = 3'
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a Javascript array-like object.  [This article](https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-7/array-like-objects) has a nice explanation.  Sample code quoted from linked article:

```
var a = {};  // Start with a regular empty object

// Add properties to make it "array-like"
var i = 0;
while(i < 10) {
    a[i] = i * i;
    i++;
}
a.length = i; // magic!!

// Now iterate through it as if it were a real array
var total = 0;
for(var j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
    total += a[j];
```

Note the `a.length = i` step makes the object look like an array to an end-user, so it can be iterated over.

FTR what confused me (this is a self-answer) was Chrome's Dev Tools adds meta-data when displaying `NamedNodeMap`.  But there is nothing "fancy" going on at JS level.

Comment: why do you reference page that needs "facebook" login i dont know

Comment: but @djechlin i can't i don't have facebook so i don't know whats inside and that was my point